# Django: json serializer returns an array not a dictionary

Tags: objective-c, django, json, dictionary

I've created a simple Django view that returns all objects, of a certain table.

```
objects_list = MyObjectClass.objects.all()
json_data = json.dumps({"objects":objects_list})
```

when I receive the request from the server it returns as Array i.e.

```
**[**{pram1:value1, param2:value2, "fields": {param3: val3, param4:val4}}, {pram1a:value1a, param2a:value2a, "fields": {param3a: val3a, param4a:val4a}}....{pram1b:value1b, param2b:value2b, "fields": {param3: val3, param4:val4}}**]**
```

which makes the parsing in objective-c first as `__NSCFArray` not a dictionary, and then treat each "cell" as a dictionary,

I'm looking for a way that returns a dictionary not an array, is there a way to achieve it?
(In objective C im using AFNetworking for serialize deserialize.)

Answer (score 0):

a list of items gets serialized to an array, to have  them in an object you can serialize it within one

ie.

```
In [1]: import json 

In [2]: json.dumps({"objects":[1,2,3,4]})
Out[2]: '{"objects": [1, 2, 3, 4]}'
```

Comment: this also returns an array

Comment: Ive updated the example with output that shows it returns an object.